# What does it print? (Lists)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, printing

I am having a hard time understanding this piece of code, it is an exercise for my upcoming exam. Help!

The programming language is python 2.7.5. The question is; What does is print?

I know the answer is `[5]` but i do not understand why. More specific, what happens within the `india()` function, can't follow it when it calls for `india(list2, elem)`.

```
def india(juliet, kilo):
    juliet[:] = juliet[1:3] + [kilo]
    kilo = juliet[1] + 1

def tilt(l):
    return l[2:]

list = [9,8,7,6]
elem = 5
list2 = list
india(list2, elem)
list = tilt(list2)
print list
```

Comment: @RedX: No need to be so discourteous. A debugger is a more advanced tool than most beginners can handle.

Comment: @MartijnPieters He is taking a course in python, so i would think that they have had a debugger introduced in the course (hopefully). If not, now is a good time to learn.

Comment: Ever heard of [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_(Python)) ?

Comment: @RedX: A debugger here won't tell you anything about value references, rebinding, and mutating a mutable list object through slice assignment though.

Comment: @RedX I never touched a debugger through my half a dozen or so coding classes in college. It was until my professional career started that I was introduced to things like breakpoints, call stack, source control, the works. It's something I wish I knew more about in college, because it makes life so much easier. But, I'm glad at the same time; made me think more about code structure/flow

Comment: The user is asking for explanation - I can't quite understand why is this question downvoted. It's a shame people discourage newbie programmers from using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what happens step by step:

1. `juliet[1:3] + [kilo]`: slice the input list, taking the second and third values, and concatenate a new list with the `kilo` value in it. Result: `[8, 7, 5]`.
2. Assign the result of the expression in step 1 to the whole slice of `juliet`; this replaces all indices *in* the list with the values of the new list created in 1. Result: the list object referenced by `juliet` now holds the values `[8, 7, 5]`.
3. Assign the second value in the new `juliet`, plus 1, to `kilo`, result is that `kilo` is rebound to `8`.

The last step is otherwise inconsequential, only the local `kilo` name was *rebound*, leaving the original variable passed to the `india()` function untouched. The list referenced by `julia` on the other hand, was altered *in place*, meaning that the `list2` and `list` references to it both see the same changes reflected.

So when `india()` returns, `list` and `list2` both refer to the same list object with the contents `[8, 7, 5]`.

After this, `tilt()` returns a slice of `list2`, which would be a *new* list object, with just the last value in `list2`, so `list` is rebound to `[5]`, and this is then printed.

If you wanted to score extra points in the exam, point out that using `list` as a variable name is not a good idea as this shadows the built-in `list()` constructor.